# Counts Of Orderings Containing At Most K Of The Kth Class

Tags: code-golf, sequence, combinatorics

This challenge is about the number of orderings which contain at most \$n\$ classes and at most \$k\$ of the \$k^{\text{th}}\$ class.

One way to represent such an ordering is as a sequence of positive integers with these three restrictions:

1. A number may only appear after all lower numbers have appeared
2. All numbers which appear must be less than or equal to \$n\$
3. Any number may only appear up to as many times as its own value

As such the number of such sequences is itself a sequence, \$a(n)\$ where:

\$a(0) = 1\$, since only the empty sequence, `[]`, works;

\$a(1) = 2\$, since `[1]` now also works;

\$a(2) = 4\$, since both `[1, 2]` and `[1, 2, 2]` also work*;

\$a(3) = 16\$:

```
[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2]
```

\$a(4) = 409\$:

```
[], [1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 2], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 2, 4, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 2, 4, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 4, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 4, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 3, 4, 3, 2], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 3, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 3, 3, 2]
```

\$a(5) = 128458\$;

\$a(6) = 612887198\$;

...and so on.

* Note, for example, that `[2, 1, 2]` violates (1) while `[1, 1, 2]` violates (3).

(Other interpretations of the underlying objects being counted no doubt exist too, feel free to comment regarding these, or, even better, explain them as part of an answer.)

#### The Challenge

Write a program or function which does any of the following:

- Takes a non-negative integer, \$n\$ and outputs either:

  - \$a(n)\$
  - \$[a(0),\cdots ,a(n)]\$
- Takes a positive integer, \$n\$ and outputs either:

  - \$a(n-1)\$
  - \$[a(0),\cdots ,a(n-1)]\$
- Takes no input and outputs the sequence \$a\$ forever

---

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so try to achieve the shortest solution in your chosen language.

Also insightful answers that are not necessarily the shortest, so long as they are still well golfed, will probably be received well!

---

This sequence is not currently in the [OEIS](https://oeis.org/), and as far as I can tell neither is any trivially related sequence (e.g. `[1,1,2,11,393,12442,...]`) - if you spot any do comment.

Comment: Somewhat related sequences: [A105748](http://oeis.org/A105748) and [A192012](https://oeis.org/A192012)

Comment: I find it unacceptable that you did not provide all the examples for `a(5)`.

Comment: @NickKennedy it's meant to represent the first \$n\$ elements, so `0` gives `[]`, while 3 gives `[1,2,4]`... is there better notation I could employ? Thanks!

Comment: I guess (it allows `0` to give `[]`, but so does the second) - I can just remove it, thanks!

Comment: This is a fun, novel question! Good job, thanks for posting it.

Comment: Wonder if (6)=612887198 and further can be found mathematically instead of the brute forcey ways of the answers here.

Comment: @KjetilS. I should think so.

Comment: Can we make the assumption that the input is \$<10\$ given how quickly the results grow, or should it (given enough time/resources) work for any input (in theory)? I think I already know the answer, but asking just in case I could save a byte. ;)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen It should work in theory for unbounded \$n\$ or output \$a\$ for ever in theory - allowing for memory/precision/overflow issues in real world implementations.

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>91 ... 76</s>  74 bytes

A recursive approach. This is very fast up to \$n=5\$. Computing \$a(6)\$ takes approximately 2 minutes on my laptop.

```javascript
n=>(g=a=>1+(h=i=>i&&h(i-1)+(a[i]^i&&a[i-1]?g(b=[...a,0],b[i]++):0))(n))`1`
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYvLCoMwEEX3fsUsiswQDWbRTe3YDxFLovWRIknR0o347emsDod77tv93D5s/vMtQ3yNaeIUuMGZHTdG4cKeG5/nC/rSkELX@u4pLixN95ix51Zr7YqqK3rZlKJbRYSByBqbprhhAIaqhgB3hqtQEjgygCGGPa6jXuOM1uHlCCdJejkmeZ@W6uxMfw)

#### How?

Instead of explicitly building the sequences, we just keep track of how many times each value appears. This gives us enough information to decide which values are allowed to be added at any given time, assuming they're always added at the end of the sequence.

#### Commented

```javascript
n => (                     // n = input
  g = a =>                 // g is a recursive function taking an array a[] holding
                           // how many times each value appears in the sequence
  1 + (                    // increment the final result
    h = i =>               // h is a recursive function taking i = next value to try
      i &&                 //   stop if i = 0
      h(i - 1) + (         //   otherwise, do a recursive call to h with i - 1
        a[i] ^ i &&        //   if i does not appear i times (rule #3)
        a[i - 1] ?         //   and i - 1 appears at least once (rule #1):
          g(               //     add the result of a recursive call to g:
            b = [...a, 0], //       define b[] as a copy of a[] with an extra '0'
                           //       so that b[i] is guaranteed to be defined
                           //       (at this point, we know that a[0] to a[i-1] exist)
            b[i]++         //       increment b[i]
          )                //     end of recursive call to g
        :                  //   else:
          0                //     add nothing
      )                    //
  )(n)                     // initial call to h with the maximum value i = n (rule #2)
)`1`                       // initial call to g with a[0] = '1', which is required to
                           // to allow i = 1 to be added as per rule #1
```

Answer (score 7):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 13 bytes

```
lfUI{T{.ysmRh
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Pyct1LM6pFqvsjg3CMg1BgA)

Let's go through this step by step, starting at the end:

- `mRh`: This autoexpands to `mRhdQ`. This means "Map the function `m` with right input `hd` over the input `Q`."

  - `Q` is an integer (e.g. 3) so it gets automatically cast to a range (e.g. [0, 1, 2]).
  - The `m` function is the map function.
  - `d` is defined to be the input to the map function.
  - `h` is the `+ 1` function (head).
  - `m` with two numeric inputs just replicates the left input a number of times equal to the right input.
  - As a result, `mRh` outputs a list like this: `[[0], [1, 1], [2, 2, 2]]`.
- `s`: Flatten (sum). Now we have a list like `[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2]`.
- `.y`: All permuted subsets.
- `{`: Uniquify (remove duplicates). Now we have a list like `[[], [0], [1], [2], [0, 1], ... ]`
- `fUI{T`: Filter that list on the function `UI{T`.

  - `T` is the input to the filter.
  - `{`: Uniquify the list to be filtered. Uniquify orders the unique elements in the order they first appear.
  - `UI`: Invariant under the function `U`:

    - `U`: Cast to range. So the unique elements must be `[]`, or `[0]`, or `[0, 1]`, etc. to pass this test.
- `l`: Length. The result is implicitly printed.

To see the orderings, just remove the `l`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 18 bytes

```
x`€FŒ!QJƑ$Ƈ¹Ƥ€ẎQL‘
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/78i4VHTGrejkxQDvY5NVDnWfmjnsSVAkYe7@gJ9HjXM@P//vzEA)

An initial attempt at a Jelly answer. A monadic link taking an integer and returning an integer. Too slow for n>3 on TIO.

### Explanation

```
x`€                | Repeat each of 1..n itself times
   F               | Flatten
    Œ!             | Permutations
         $Ƈ        | Keep those where the following is true:
      Q            | - Uniquify
       JƑ          | - Check whether invariant when a sequence along the list is generated
           ¹Ƥ€     | Prefixes of each
              Ẏ    | Join outer lists
               Q   | Uniquify
                L  | Length
                 ‘ | Add one (to account for the empty list)
```

## Longer but handles \$n=5\$ in under 25 seconds on TIO

### [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 24 bytes

```
ċⱮṀ$;0ḣ³<J$T;€)Ẏ
“”WÇƬẈS
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9qZWxsef//xIvisa7huYAkOzDhuKPCszxKJFQ74oKsKeG6jgrigJzigJ1Xw4fGrOG6iFP///81)

Thanks to @JonathanAllan for improving the final bit of the faster version!

Answer (score 4):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>113</s> <s>106</s> 98 bytes

```r
g=function(n,N=1:n,B=N*0){for(e in N[c(1,B)[-n-1]>0&(F=all(B<=N))])F=F+g(n,,'[<-'(B,e,B[e]+1));+F}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcuxCsIwEADQ3a/oZO/MBRK1i/YcMmTMD4QMUtJQKFcoOonfHs3ytrfXWnh@y/RaNgGhwPYm5DicDH7mbYfcLdKFOIElh1GLtulhjuD5ua7gRg6ICT17Vf6b@jjqHhxlcjEnZRHvyn9rAYOHArZxblwa18aA9Qc)

- -9 bytes thanks to @RobinRyder
- -2 bytes using @Arnauld idea of storing occurrences table only (I just noticed that basically I was using the same approach, but creating the actual list too)

Comment: I don't understand your code yet, but `double()` can be `1[0]` for -4 bytes. It seems that setting `x=0` also works, for -7 bytes instead.

Comment: @RobinRyder I'm really rusty... thanks! :D

Comment: Welcome back! [102 bytes](https://tio.run/##Fcy7CsMgFADQvV@R8V6ioH0sbezg4OgPhAxWVAS5gWAgUPrtNi5nPFtrScWdfM0rAbFDCaZVdZ@9uBrgYITMKvkk/OYIZuKuFNCTsohx3SAMmQY7e5BM48yJy@UtFjTKjOnc/BkExNdofi2BwEsC2bl2bp1754HtDw "R – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 100 bytes

Relatively simple answer similar to the Jelly solution, but it's able to calculate for n=4 without timing out on TIO (albeit taking 30 seconds to do so), which Jelly can't at time of writing.

```ruby
->n{r=(1..n).flat_map{|j|[j]*j};i=0;r.sum{r.permutation(i+=1).uniq.count{|a|a.uniq==[*1..a.max]}}+1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxLCsIwEADQq7jsBwcD7sp4kRDKKI0kmI/pBCpJzh7F5du8lO@frrGfb74kHASAH0G/iFdHsVRbpVWTbYvBy5Jgz64kiFtymYlN8IOZUYyQvXnDI2TPpVKlvxHl9OsIHB2qtVm0Hk9aPjfegcNqVL9@AQ)

Answer (score 2):

## [Raku](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 94 bytes

```perl6
{1+set map ~*,grep {all .unique Z==^$_},.permutations>>[[\,] ^$_][*;*]}o{(^$_ Zxx 1..$_)[*;*]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JY1LCsMgAAWv8hahtFaEQOkmmIPEmuDClIAm1g8kSHp1K3Q5M4tx2ptnsQcuMzhKbu9BR1jl8CX07bVDVsaApXX5JI2B87GZTsqc9jZFFZdtDX0vxItK1CIF6Yg8t3ytgGHf0TLWTLe/LkEdYPU0bx7joys/)

Times out for \$n>3\$, mostly since it is running the same filter for all prefixes of all permutations of the largest list (i.e. `[1,2,2,3,3,3,...n]`). This results in a lot of duplicates that have to filtered out later.

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>19</s> <s>18</s> 17 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
ÝDÅΓœ€Œ€`ÙʒÙāQ}g>
```

Pretty slow (\$n=3\$ in about <s>5.5</s> 0.5 seconds on TIO), but it works.

Inspired by [*@isaacg*'s Pyth answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/198584/52210).
I have the feeling this can definitely be golfed by at least a few bytes, though.
-1 byte thanks to *@ExpiredData*.
-1 byte and sped up by changing the order of some operations thanks to *@Grimmy*.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FyXw63nJh@dfGrS4ZlHGgNrHzWtObcdSCQcnplu9/@/MQA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##ATcAyP9vc2FiaWX/M8aSTj8iIOKGkiAiP07/w51Ew4XOk8WTypLDmcSBUX3igqzOt@KCrGDDmWc@/yz/).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ý                  # Push a list in the range [0, (implicit) input]                        
                   # (NOTE: `L` cannot be used here, because input=0 would become [1,0])
 D                 # Duplicate this list
  ÅΓ               # Run-length encode the lists, to have each value repeat itself that
                   # many times (i.e. [1,2,3,4] → [1,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,4])
    œ              # Take all permutations of this list
     ʒ             # Filter this list of lists by:
      Ù            #  Uniquify it
       ā           #  Push a list in the range [1, length] (without popping the list itself)
        Q          #  Check if both lists are equal
         }€η       # After the filter: take the prefixes of each remaining permutation
            €`     # Flatten one level
              Ù    # Uniquify the list of lists
               g   # After the filter: get the amount of remaining lists by taking the length
                >  # + 1 for the missing `[]`
                   # (after which this is output implicitly)
```

Minor (but even slower) alternative: `` $ÝDÅΓœ€Œ€`ÙvyÙāQO ``: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f9f5fBcl8Ot5yYfnfyoac3RSUAi4fDMssrDM480Bvr//28EAA) or [verify a few more test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/W90bJKfvZLCo7ZJCkr2/w39Ds91Odx6bvLRyY@a1hydBCQSDs8sqzw880hjoP//Wp3/AA).

```python
$                  # Push 1 and the input
 ÝDÅΓœ             # Same as above
      €Œ           # Get all sublists of each permutation
        €`Ù        # Same as above
           v       # Loop over each inner list `y`
            y      #  Push list `y`
             ÙāQ   #  Same as above
                O  #  Take the sum of the stack
                   # (after the loop, the result is output implicitly)
```

Comment: Why do you need to sort the list of suffixes? Since permutations for any ordering of the same list should be the same shouldn't they?

Comment: @ExpiredData Oops, you're completely right, thanks. The sort was still there from a previous attempt of generating all permutations of all lengths, for which 05AB1E unfortunately doesn't have any builtins a.f.a.i.k., unlike Pyth.

Comment: `Ý¦.s˜` => `ÝD×S` for -1. `€Œ` before filtering => `€η` after filtering for a massive speedup at no cost in bytes. [TIO with both changes](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FyXw9ODj04@NenwzCONgbWPmtac2w4kEg7PTLf7/98YAA).

Comment: @Grimmy `ÝD×S` would fail for inputs \$>9\$, though. I've asked OP whether we can assume the input is \$<10\$, although I have the feeling I know the answer already. I will edit to add the sped up though, thanks!

Comment: Oh whoops. You can use [`ÝDÅΓ`](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//8FyXw63nJv//b2gAAA) then.

Comment: @Grimmy That works, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 150 bytes

```perl
sub f{my$n=pop;$n?do{my%e;@f=f($n-1);push@f,map{$f=$_;grep!$e{$_}++,map$f=~s/.{$_}/$&$n/r,$n==1?0:index($f,$n-1)+1||9e9..length$f}@f for 1..$n;@f}:''}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Nc5RT4NADAfw932KSqoHActI5GGcF/geahaXXTcMlAuwxIXhV8fDxb71l/7bOts3@bIMlwPw1F5RjOucRimPnW8fra7YcIjynEXaXYZzxUn76SZkg3t96q17QDvhfo7j1T3/DCmtkOITStonfqPJym1Ry9F@h8jJ3644u912dkfUWDmNZ@S5YuCuh4wIxR@dC6XmZZX2CigQbonyaNqALy9@2sD6V6T/CZt6GL2ivOZQgnpT9NXVEqpEJRVHpD4UFKDUPeD6WkYIUAoIqGIK7vl3CfRmXl5@AQ)

Produces the correct output in about two seconds for up to n=5.

Out of memory for n=6. And would not work anyway for n>9 (two digit numbers).

Thought about using a permutation solution like @Value Ink's Ruby answer, but could'nt find a core perl function or module that generated perm's and including a permutation function would probably add just way too many bytes.

With indentation, comments and test run:

```perl
sub f {
    my $n = pop;
    $n == 0 ? ('')
  : $n == 1 ? ('',1)
  : do {
      my %e;                                   #keep track of existing elements (strings)
      @f = f($n-1);                            #start with f(n-1) array
      push @f, map{                            #expand f array n times
        $f = $_;                               #f = current @f element
        grep !$e{$_}++,                        #don't add if already exists
          map $f =~ s/.{$_}/$&$n/r,            #insert n char at current position
            index($f,$n-1)+1||9e9 .. length$f  #loop positions from first occurence of n-1 to end
      } @f
        for 1..$n;
      @f                                       #return expanded @f array (string sequences)
    }
}

# test:
for my $n (0..5){
  my @f = f($n);
  my $list = $n<5 ? '['.join(',',map"'$_'",@f).']' : '';
  print "$n: ".@f." $list\n";
}
```

Output:

```perl
0: 1 ['']
1: 2 ['','1']
2: 4 ['','1','12','122']
3: 16 ['','1','12','122','123','1232','1223','1233','12332','12323','12233','12333','123332','123323','123233','122333']
4: 409 ['','1','12','122','123','1232','1223','1233','12332','12323','12233','12333','123332','123323','123233','122333','1234','12342','12324','12234','12343','12334','123432','123342','123324','123423','123243','123234','122343','122334','123433','123343','123334','1234332','1233432','1233342','1233324','1234323','1233423','1233243','1233234','1234233','1232433','1232343','1232334','1223433','1223343','1223334','12344','123442','123424','123244','122344','123443','123434','123344','1234432','1234342','1234324','1233442','1233424','1233244','1234423','1234243','1234234','1232443','1232434','1232344','1223443','1223434','1223344','1234433','1234343','1234334','1233443','1233434','1233344','12344332','12343432','12343342','12343324','12334432','12334342','12334324','12333442','12333424','12333244','12344323','12343423','12343243','12343234','12334423','12334243','12334234','12332443','12332434','12332344','12344233','12342433','12342343','12342334','12324433','12324343','12324334','12323443','12323434','12323344','12234433','12234343','12234334','12233443','12233434','12233344','123444','1234442','1234424','1234244','1232444','1223444','1234443','1234434','1234344','1233444','12344432','12344342','12344324','12343442','12343424','12343244','12334442','12334424','12334244','12332444','12344423','12344243','12344234','12342443','12342434','12342344','12324443','12324434','12324344','12323444','12234443','12234434','12234344','12233444','12344433','12344343','12344334','12343443','12343434','12343344','12334443','12334434','12334344','12333444','123444332','123443432','123443342','123443324','123434432','123434342','123434324','123433442','123433424','123433244','123344432','123344342','123344324','123343442','123343424','123343244','123334442','123334424','123334244','123332444','123444323','123443423','123443243','123443234','123434423','123434243','123434234','123432443','123432434','123432344','123344423','123344243','123344234','123342443','123342434','123342344','123324443','123324434','123324344','123323444','123444233','123442433','123442343','123442334','123424433','123424343','123424334','123423443','123423434','123423344','123244433','123244343','123244334','123243443','123243434','123243344','123234443','123234434','123234344','123233444','122344433','122344343','122344334','122343443','122343434','122343344','122334443','122334434','122334344','122333444','1234444','12344442','12344424','12344244','12342444','12324444','12234444','12344443','12344434','12344344','12343444','12334444','123444432','123444342','123444324','123443442','123443424','123443244','123434442','123434424','123434244','123432444','123344442','123344424','123344244','123342444','123324444','123444423','123444243','123444234','123442443','123442434','123442344','123424443','123424434','123424344','123423444','123244443','123244434','123244344','123243444','123234444','122344443','122344434','122344344','122343444','122334444','123444433','123444343','123444334','123443443','123443434','123443344','123434443','123434434','123434344','123433444','123344443','123344434','123344344','123343444','123334444','1234444332','1234443432','1234443342','1234443324','1234434432','1234434342','1234434324','1234433442','1234433424','1234433244','1234344432','1234344342','1234344324','1234343442','1234343424','1234343244','1234334442','1234334424','1234334244','1234332444','1233444432','1233444342','1233444324','1233443442','1233443424','1233443244','1233434442','1233434424','1233434244','1233432444','1233344442','1233344424','1233344244','1233342444','1233324444','1234444323','1234443423','1234443243','1234443234','1234434423','1234434243','1234434234','1234432443','1234432434','1234432344','1234344423','1234344243','1234344234','1234342443','1234342434','1234342344','1234324443','1234324434','1234324344','1234323444','1233444423','1233444243','1233444234','1233442443','1233442434','1233442344','1233424443','1233424434','1233424344','1233423444','1233244443','1233244434','1233244344','1233243444','1233234444','1234444233','1234442433','1234442343','1234442334','1234424433','1234424343','1234424334','1234423443','1234423434','1234423344','1234244433','1234244343','1234244334','1234243443','1234243434','1234243344','1234234443','1234234434','1234234344','1234233444','1232444433','1232444343','1232444334','1232443443','1232443434','1232443344','1232434443','1232434434','1232434344','1232433444','1232344443','1232344434','1232344344','1232343444','1232334444','1223444433','1223444343','1223444334','1223443443','1223443434','1223443344','1223434443','1223434434','1223434344','1223433444','1223344443','1223344434','1223344344','1223343444','1223334444']
5: 128458
```

Comment: Is there a fix you can make to have this work (at least in theory given enough resources) for any \$n\$? Otherwise it's not currently a valid answer (I still up-voted it as it is a nice method),

Comment: It DO work for any n in theory – even though the computer needed would quickly grow beyond the size of the universe and run the age of it as n grows.  I think your comment also apply at least as much for at least a couple of the other answers here as well (I see permutation methods), with more up-votes and ability to do lesser n's. So unfair...go figure :-)

Comment: I'm talking about the fact that there is a limit to numbers which are less than 10 due to you use of grep & the like.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 34 bytes

```
Ｎθ⊞υυＦυＦθＦ∧∨¬κ№ι⊖κ‹№ικ⊕κ⊞υ⁺ι⟦κ⟧ＩＬυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY4xC8IwEIV3f8WNF4ijUyepS6HU7uIQ09OWpkmb5Pz7MREVnN7B9x3v6VF57ZRJqbErx46XG3ncRLXrOYzIEjjfd@cBWcA7t08e7YBnj52LOAsJtWMbcZJwIu1pIRtpyEBk1FII@ONFbuy/I@Bb1xsOxbrMV1FW@Cl/1SpEbMk@YnayXaV0SPuneQE) Link is to verbose version of code. Builds up all `a(n)` lists in memory, so TIO will only go up to `n=5`. Explanation:

```
Ｎθ
```

Input `n`.

```
⊞υυ
```

Start with a sequence with no digits. (Alternatively, I could start with a list containing `-1`; this would cost 3 bytes here and then save 3 bytes because I don't need to special case the first digit below.)

```
Ｆυ
```

Loop through each sequence as it is discovered.

```
Ｆθ
```

Loop through each available digit. (These are 0-indexed, so each digit `i` must be less than `n` and can be added if there are no more than `i` digits `i` so far.)

```
Ｆ∧∨¬κ№ι⊖κ‹№ικ⊕κ
```

Check that the digit is legal.

```
⊞υ⁺ι⟦κ⟧
```

If so then append this sequence to the list.

```
ＩＬυ
```

Output the total number of sequences found.